# Label shows text in iOS 6 but not in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, label

I have a view of my app that shows information in labels, the issue is that this labels are empty in iOS 7 but works fine in iOS 6 and I can't find why.

This is the method used for getting the view controller and show the data:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

ShoppeDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[ShoppeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShoppeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

PDLocation *pdLocationPhone = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

detailViewController.phone = pdLocationPhone.telephone;
detailViewController.callMe = pdLocationPhone.callMe;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

PDLocation *pdLocation = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detailViewController.shoppeLabel.text = pdLocation.name;
detailViewController.addressLabel.text = pdLocation.description;

CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:pdLocation.location.latitude longitude:pdLocation.location.longitude];
CLLocationDistance distance = [_userLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
 if (distance < 0.1) {
 detailViewController.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bienvenido"];
 } else {

     [detailViewController.distanceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Estás a %.01f Km", distance/1000]];
 }

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I can't make it work in iOS 7, Any ideas?

Thank you!

***This is the XIB file***

[image: XIB file showing label ubication]

Comment: Are you sure they are empty or do they display the text in white on white or so?

Comment: Not a color issue I have tried that, the thing is that labels shows content in iOS 6 but not in iOS 7, if I put some default text iOS 7 the labels shows that text.

Answer (score 0):

Check label's `backgroundColor` and `textColor`. Seems like it's an issue with colors.